# Libgdx AndroidApplication native(?) crash

Tags: libgdx

I have a strange problem. I use a nightly from last week. If I recall correctly it's from 23/3. 
What happens is that I run a Libgdx Activity and it runs fine. Than I finish the app. I start the libgdx activity again and it crashes... This happens a lot but not all the time. 
In debug mode it doesn't happen at all. Any ideas? It doesn't print any crash log but I think it has something to do with this log: http://pastebin.com/3BFrjbES

My code doesn't do any thing special right now. It's just printing the FPS in a stage....

I think there is an error in the log that may be connected: EGL error: EGL_BAD_CONTEXT.
This is printed just before the previous log.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you calling dispose on everything?

Comment: Yes. It's really only the stage that needs to be disposed.

Comment: You should have more Disposable objects than just a Stage. Mali is part of your GPU system and you are crashing while attempting to perform some type of locking operation in the GPU system. Release everything - see https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management

Comment: I don't have anything else to dispose, because I am only showing my fps in a stage using a Label. That's it.

Comment: A Label is text so that means either a Skin or BitmapFont.

Comment: Alright, didn't noticed that I needed to dispose the BitmapFont. I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: @Chase, not working still getting: EGL error: EGL_BAD_CONTEXT

Comment: Out of ideas at this point, maybe post the entire code to your app and we can see if there is anything else. What is the device?

Comment: I found out the problem. I don't know why it happens, I am still testing. The problem disappeared after I removed hardwareAccelaration="true" from my application tag in the manifest. I don't know why it matters as my device is 4.0.4 which means that it's enabled by default...

Comment: Cool, please add this as a self-answer when you figure everything out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. The problem disappeared after I removed hardwareAccelaration="true" from my application tag in the manifest. I don't know why it matters as my device is 4.0.4 which means that it's enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

What does "finish the app" mean? A pause (pressing home) or a destroy?

I wonder if it is any way related to LibGDX attempting to preserve the EGL Context. The default for Android is to not preserve it but LibGDX attempts to enable it if you are on SDK >= 11. You could try to disable preservation in your AndroidApplication subclass by doing something like:

```
View view = ((AndroidGraphics)Gdx.graphics).getView();
try {
    Method method = null;
    for (Method m : view.getClass().getMethods()) {
        if (m.getName().equals("setPreserveEGLContextOnPause")) {
            method = m;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (method != null) {
        method.invoke((GLSurfaceView20)view, false);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```